vscode gdb debugger not showing qt variables c++
I want to use VSCode to write Qt projects, since the Qt Creator is really hard to use.
But the debugger in VSCode just can't show the real value of Qt variables which is really upset.
I have this configuration in launch.json:
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gdb-Debug",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/path/to/exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Qt\\Tools\\mingw730_64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "visualizerFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/qt5.natvis",
            "showDisplayString": true,
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty printing",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "make-debug-all"
        }
    

And I have download the natvis file from here: https://github.com/qt-labs/vstools/blob/dev/QtMSBuild/QtMsBuild/qt5.natvis.xml.
And I use mingw not msvc to compile the project.
But when use the debugger it still not showing the exact value of the Qt variables, like QString.
It just show some really wired thing.

Seems like it just show the address, and I can't see the real value stores in it. Even qDebug() won't print the right value.
I don't know what else to do or which step I'm wrong? Can someone help me out?

Natvis is for visual studio, not gdb or vs code. Gdb debug helpers are implemented using python.

@Botje there's a useful step you can do before you say words. if you do it, you could find things like https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/natvis

Well, TIL! Now all OP has to do is figure out whether VS code is at fault, their mingw installation, the incomplete natvis implementation, the natvis bindings, or Qt! It sure would be concenient if someone were to package some of these components into an integrated development environment instead of the random grab bag of stuff that is VS code...
